# Bit manipulation- for negative numbers

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Let the size of integer ***i=-5*** be 2 bytes. The **signed bit** value at the leftmost bit is '1'(which signifies that it is a negative number). 
When i am trying to do a right shift operation, should i not expect the '1' at the 15th bit position to shift to 14th position? and give me a high but positive value?

What i tried:

```
int i=5;
i>>1 // giving me 2 (i understand this)

int i=-5
i>>1 // giving me -3 (mind=blown)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right shifts of negative values are implementation-defined, [expr.shift]/3

> The value of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. 
>   [..]. **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
>   value is implementation-defined.**

Most implementations use the so-called [**arithmetic shift**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) though, **which preserves and extends the sign-bit**:

> Shifting right by *n* bits on a two's complement signed binary number
>   **has the effect of dividing it by *2<sup>n</sup>***, but it always rounds down
>   (towards negative infinity). This is different from the way rounding
>   is usually done in signed integer division (which rounds towards 0).
>   This discrepancy has led to bugs in more than one compiler.

So what happens is, when shortened down to 8 bit, the following. In two's complement -5 would be

```
1111 1011
```

After the arithmetic right shift:

```
1111 1101
```

Now flip and add one to get the positive value for comparison:

```
0000 0011
```

Looks like a three to me.

Comment: I worked on your solution. So how i understood is. if we have to right shift a negative number here is how i will proceed. If we have to right shift a number -x. 1.Write binary for x. 2. Convert into 2's complement. 3. Right shift ('1' at the leftmost is sticky) . 4.calculate 2's complement again. Now that's the answer with a '-' sign.

Comment: Does this makes sense?

Comment: @SeasonalShot .. how about dividing by 2^n? And no, your method is not completely correct (in particular, if the number is -x then you write the binary representation of -x, not x). Then you already have the 2's complement representation, which is the number itself, not some transformation of it. It's just another way of expressing the same thing.