# Negative number right shift operator in C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm new to C++ and I find something I can't understand. Could anyone provide some help?

For the following codes:

```
int i = -3;
printf("i=%d\n",i);
i = i >> 1:
printf("i >> 1 evaluates to: %d\n", i);
```

then I got the result:

i=-3
i >> 1 evaluates to: -2

I don't quite understand. 
As 3 is coded as( let is be simple):

```
3 : 0000 0011
-3 : 1111 1100
```

then after right shift operation, we should have:

```
-1 : 1111 1110
```

right? Why I got -2? (My PC in 64 bit)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, `-3` is `1111 1101`, `-2` is `1111 1110` and `-1` is `1111 1111`

Comment: No 1111 1110=-2, -1 is 1111 1111.

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954788/bit-manipulation-for-negative-numbers) with a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that because 3 is `00000011`, -3 is represented simply by inverting bits (the so-called "one's complement" representation of negative numbers) to get `11111100`. And that likewise `00000001` becomes `11111110` when negated.  In fact that's not the case—instead your computer seems to be using the almost-universal ["two's complement" system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in which -3 is represented as `11111101`, -2 is `11111110` and -1 is `11111111`.

One nice intuition pump for the two's-complement system is to consider a series of increments, and to note that the behavior is somewhat consistent and intuitive regardless of whether you imagine them happening in the bit pattern itself, in the signed representation, or in the unsigned.  Let's stick to 8 bits for simplicity (imagine the "9th bit" just getting discarded):

```
bit pattern           interpreted as...
               signed byte    unsigned byte
11111101            -3             253
11111110            -2             254
11111111            -1             255
00000000             0               0  (wrap-around)
00000001             1               1
```

When it goes from -1 to 0 I can almost "hear" all those bits flipping over one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `-1` = `0xFFFF` = `1111 1111 1111 1111b`, `-3` = `0xFFFD` = `1111 1111 1111 1101b`(for 4 byte `int`).

So when you use right shift, you get `1111 1111 1111 1110b` which is `-2`